# Add iTextSharp.xmlworker.dll to use XML Worker

Tags: xml, worker

I was using HTML Worker (iTextSharp version 5.5.0) but I need to change my code to use XML Worker.

I tried XML Worker version 5.5.0 which it seems it does not support the below namespace :
using iTextSharp.tool.xml;

So I tried to download  XML Worker version 5.5.3 but still not working.
Should I remove previous iTextSharp version 5.5.0 and add iTextSharp version 5.5.3?

Could you please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I removed iTextSharp version 5.5.0 then
 added XML Worker version 5.5.3 and iTextSharp version 5.5.3.

It is working now.

XML worker is more complicated than HTML Worker. I'm reading tutorials to understand how to use it and replace it with HTML Worker.

Please let me know if you have a good instruction.

Thanks